# LetsEncrypt generates fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files. I need .crt and .key files. How can I get them?

Tags: ssl, websocket, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

After running `sudo certbot --nginx -d mydomain.io -d www.mydomain.io`

I'm getting:

```
Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem
Your key file has been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem
```

For my app to work, I need `private.key` and `certificate.crt` files.

I have tried converting `.pem` files like so:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem -out certificate.crt
openssl rsa -outform der -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem -out private.key
```

When trying to run my app, I'm getting this error in the browser dev tools:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<my-ip>:<my-port>/' failed: 
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

On server I'm getting this error (apparently it means that my app couldn't parse the key file):

```
mbedtls error: returned -0x7780
```

So it looks like an issue with the certificate. Can you help me to figure out what I have done wrong? What could be causing this issue? Are there other ways to generate `.crt` and `.key` files, so I could double check that I didn't make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem wasn't related to generating the keys, I was doing it correctly.

But the client version of my app was trying to connect to `wss://<my-ip>:<my-port>/`, and instead I was supposed to connect to `wss://<my-domain-name>:<my-port>/`.